# OrientDB change @rid (metadata)

Tags: metadata, orientdb

Is it possible to change the @rid (metadata) when inserting a row ??
Ex : When a table having the last record rid as #40:10 can we add a record with the rid #40:15 ??

Comment: Check out [ask].  What research have you done?  What have you tried?

Answer (score 3):

It is not possible.
@rid is assigned by OrientDB and cannot be changed.

http://orientdb.com/docs/2.1/Tutorial-Record-ID.html